# How to Write Where Clause Condition in Rails using AND & OR Operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
def self.get_previous_feedback current_feedback
    Feedback.where("feedbacks.id < ?", current_feedback.id).order('created_at asc').last
end

def self.get_next_feedback current_feedback
    Feedback.where("feedbacks.id > ?", current_feedback.id).order('created_at asc').first
end
#current_feeedback is the show page of any feedback.( feedback/show/id=2)
```

1. I have got 3 tables in my DB. Feedback, User, Department are connected in one-many relation.
2. By running above codes I am able to navigate to next/previous Feedback.
3. My User (current_user) is logged in, and Now on clicking prev/next, I want to retrieve the next feedback from DB(where condition written above) + whose feedback.department_id = current_user.deparment_id.
4. For including department_id in need to write an AND statement. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
def self.get_previous_feedback(current_feedback,current_user)
    Feedback.where("id < ? & department_id = ?", current_feedback.id, current_user.department_id).order('created_at asc').last
end

def self.get_next_feedback(current_feedback,current_user)
    Feedback.where("id > ? & department_id = ?", current_feedback.id, current_user.department_id).order('created_at asc').first
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me out the correct logic.
Above query needs bit modification to work correctly.

1. simply id does not link to the feedbacks table, hence had to use feedbacks.id
2. & needs to be replaced by  AND.
3. Corrected Code :

   Feedback.where("feedbacks.id < ? AND feedbacks.department_id = ?",
       current_feedback.id, current_user.department_id).order('created_at
       asc').last

Thanks Man ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also chain the two conditions, that way you don't need use the `AND` and you can also re-use the `department_id` clause.

```
def self.get_department_feedback current_user
    Feedback.where(department_id: current_user.deparment_id)
end

def self.get_previous_feedback(current_feedback,current_user)
    get_deparment_feedback(current_user).where("feedbacks.id < ?", current_feedback.id).order('created_at asc').last
end

def self.get_next_feedback(current_feedback,current_user)
    get_deparment_feedback(current_user).where("feedbacks.id > ?", current_feedback.id).order('created_at asc').first
end
```